# gstreamer on Rpi3, after gst-launch-1.0 reboot to white login screen

Tags: pi-3, streaming-video, login

Whenever I use gstreamer to play a media file:

```
    gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///home/pi/test.mkv
```

it always immediately reboot to the white login screen.

Have anyone encountered this? I have enabled openGL driver and increased gpu_mem to 256.

Comment: What kind of power supply do you have?

Answer (score 0):

It is about GL driver. Test it without GL enabled.